# Network error when sending audio and video telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm making a bot using the python-telegram-bot lib.
Every text message i send works fine, but i must send videos and audio as well and that doesn't work.
I'm sending them like this:

```
bot.send_audio(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, audio=open(path, 'rb'), timeout=3600)
bot.send_video(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, video=open(path, 'rb'), timeout=3600)
```

The calls are using different paths and the timeout is high because of my internet connection, after deployment i will change it.
The error message:

```
telegram.error.NetworkError: urllib3 HTTPError ('Connection aborted', ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 'An estabilished connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an antivirus or firewall may be blocking your requests. Try temporarily disabling them or add an exception if you can.